# How to distribute the view uniformly using auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to display four views using auto layout, to disperse them uniformly in horizontal orientation. I want to specify the leading space to the container view for the first view, and the trailing space for the fourth view, and the second and third view should be dispersed uniformly and all the four views have the same width. How can I do that ?